# Prove that $2$, $3$, $1+ \sqrt{-5}$, and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, divisibility

So the Norm for an element $\alpha = a + b\sqrt{-5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is defined as $N(\alpha) = a^2 + 5b^2$ and so i argue by contradiction assume there exists $\alpha$ such that $N(\alpha) = 2$ and so $a^2+5b^2 = 2$ , however, since $b^2$ and $a^2$ are both positive integers then $b=0$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$ however $a$ must be an integer and so no such $\alpha$ exists, same goes for $3$.

I already proved that

1. $N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.
2. if $\alpha\mid\beta$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, then $N(\alpha)\mid N(\beta)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
3. $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a unit if and only if $N(\alpha)=1$.
4. Show that there are no elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ with $N(\alpha)=2$ or $N(\alpha)=3$. (I proved it above)

Now I need to prove that $2$, $3$, $1+ \sqrt{-5}$, and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible.

So I also argue by contradiction, assume $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ is reducible then there must exists Non unit elements $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1 + \sqrt{-5} $ and so $N(\alpha\beta) =N(\alpha)N(\beta)= N(1 + \sqrt{-5}) = 6$ but we already know that $N(\alpha) \neq 2$ or $3$ and so $N(\alpha) = 6$ and $N(\beta) = 1$ or vice verse , in any case this contradicts the fact that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both non units.I just want to make sure i am on the right track here. And how can i prove that $2$, $3$, $1+ \sqrt{-5}$, and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ are not associate to each other.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86383/proving-2-3-1-sqrt-5-and-1-sqrt-5-are-irreducible-in-mathbbz-sqrt

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since here OP supplies much of a proof and asks for comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. All your reasoning makes sense to me.

**On your question about the associates**

By the properties of the norm, associates have the same norm. So the only possible associates in your list are $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$.

Now determine all units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ by finding all integer solutions of $N(a + b\sqrt{-5}) = 1$. (The list will be quite short.)

Then check every unit $u$ for $u (1 + \sqrt{-5}) = (1 - \sqrt{-5})$.
You will see that this never happens and thus, the two elements are not associate.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen these same arguments in quite a few books, it all looks pretty standard issue to me.

But what you seem to be missing is the *motivation* for all of this, the why do we care. That motivation is this famous fact: $$6 = 2 \times 3 = (1 - \sqrt{-5})(1 + \sqrt{-5}).$$ It's also true that $$6 = -2 \times -3 = (-1 - \sqrt{-5})(-1 + \sqrt{-5}).$$ We've got four factorizations here, but how many of them are distinct factorizations into irreducibles?

Well, $6$ has a norm of $36$. Per the familiar arguments you've already quoted, $2, 3, 1 - \sqrt{-5}, 1 + \sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible with norms of $4, 9, 6, 6$ respectively, and $36 = 4 \times 9 = 6 \times 6$.

I suppose you also need a good definition of associates: in a commutative ring, $x$ and $y$ are associates *if and only if* there is a unit $u$ such that $x = uy$ (see https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Associate/Commutative_Ring). In an imgainary quadratic ring like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, if $u$ is a unit and $x$ and $y$ are associates, then $N(u) = 1$ and $N(x) = N(y)$.

Clearly $2$ is not an associate of $3$ nor of $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ nor of $1 + \sqrt{-5}$. It's possible that $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ are associates of each other. But don't jump to the conclusion that $N(x) = N(y)$ automatically means $x$ and $y$ are associates, the definition explicitly requires a unit $u$ such that $x = uy$. There are only two units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, and those are $-1$ and $1$. As it turns out, $(-1)(1 - \sqrt{-5}) = -1 + \sqrt{-5}$, not $1 + \sqrt{-5}$, so this absence of a suitable unit means that $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ are *not* associates of each other.

Although we've shown four factorizations of $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, only two of these are distinct because the other two consist of associates of numbers in the first two.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$: 1 and $-1$. To obtain the associate of a number, you multiply that number by a unit other than 1, and in this domain there is only one choice: $-1$. So, for example, the associate of 2 is $-2$, the associate of 3 is $-3$, the associate of $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ is $-1 + \sqrt{-5}$ and the associate of $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ is $-1 - \sqrt{-5}$.

You've already proven 2, 3, $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible. The arguments by norm were sufficient. However, in some other domains, like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, it becomes very important to watch out for associates.

I would like to close with some examples of "composite" numbers in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$:

- $2 \sqrt{-5}$
- $5 + 5 \sqrt{-5}$
- 21
- 29