# Relevant to Gaussian Integers

Tags: number-theory, gaussian-integers

I am stuck with part of my homework.

Let R be the following set of complex numbers: $R=\{a+bi\sqrt5 : a,b\;\text{are ordinary integers}\}$

Can you find distinct irreducibles $\pi_1,\,\pi_2,\,\pi_3,\,\pi_4,\,\pi_5,\,\pi_6$ in R with the property that $\pi_1\pi_2=\pi_3\pi_4=\pi_5\pi_6$?

cf) 'irreducible' here means irreducible into a multiple form of elements of R.

Could anyone give me a start on how to deal with this?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: These are complex integers, but Gaussian integers are usually $a+bi$

Comment: Do you know which Gaussian integers are irreducible? That would be a good place to start

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I am aware of that, but I thought it must be somewhat relevant because this question was part of the chapter on Gaussian integers.

Comment: For a start, have a look at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86383/proving-2-3-1-sqrt-5-and-1-sqrt-5-are-irreducible-in-mathbbz-sqrt). This is a popular exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi_1=2+i\sqrt 5,\pi_2=-2+i\sqrt 5,\pi_3=3,\pi_4=-3,\pi_5=-2-i\sqrt 5,\pi_6= 2-i\sqrt 5$. Note $$\pi_1\pi_2=\pi_3\pi_4=\pi_5\pi_6=-9$$

The map $\eta :R\to\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ defined by $(x+iy)\mapsto x^2+y^2$ is multiplicative ; i.e. $\eta(zz')=\eta(z)\eta(z')$ with $\eta(a+(b\sqrt5)i)=1\iff a^2+5b^2=1\iff a=\pm1\land b=0$. Moreover, note $\eta(z)=3$ has no solutions in $R$ as we'd certainly have $\text{Im}(z)=0$ but $3$ is not a perfect square. Therefore, if $\eta(z)=9$ then $z$ must be irreducible because $z=z'z''$ would then imply $\eta(z)=\eta(z')\eta(z'')=9$ implying one of $z',z''$ is a unit.